# Can I get into cappadocia after completing the ACR story?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I have completed the Assassin' Creed: Revelations story and need to get back to Cappadocia.

Is there anyway to go back?

Comment: I would like to know this as well.
I would suggest looking around the ports to see if there is a ship to take you there.

Answer (score 6):

Yes of course.  On the northern area of Constantinople, there's a ferry in the far east end of the area.  That will take you to Cappadocia.

[image: location of the ferry on the map]

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There is a ship captain on the far Eastern dock of Galata (The isolated area in the North) that will take you back there.

Comment: You can also, of course, replay a mission that takes place there.